# Reverse a Linked List with time complexity O(1)

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

Is  it possible to reverse a Linked List with time complexity of O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

(For doubly linked lists, of course. For single-linked lists it is out of the question.)

It is a very old trick.

Just keep a flag which is telling you that the linked list is 'reversed'.

When the list is not considering itself as reversed, it works as normal.

When the list is considering itself as reversed, then it swaps the meaning of `head` and `tail`, and for each node in the list, it swaps the meaning of `previous` and `next`.

Of course, for that to work, your linked list must fully encapsulate itself. You cannot have some leaky abstraction here.  (Then again, you should not have any leaky abstractions anywhere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction)

Comment: You should probably specify that this works for a doubly-linked list, not for a singly-linked list.

Comment: @Stef I took it for granted that the OP was asking about a doubly-linked list, because for a single-linked list it is out of the question. But of course you are right, it should be stated, so I added a line about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about **Singly linked list** then you cannot reverse it in less than **O(n)**.

But a **Doubly linked list** can be reversed in **O(1)** time.

Reference : [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-we-reverse-a-linked-list-in-less-than-on/#:~:text=A%20doubly%20linked%20list%20with,may%20not%20be%20considered%20valid](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-we-reverse-a-linked-list-in-less-than-on/#:%7E:text=A%20doubly%20linked%20list%20with,may%20not%20be%20considered%20valid).